# Eclipse approach vs. Netbeans for GWT compiler

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jakarta-ee, netbeans, compiler-construction

In eclipse we have separated button for compiling GWT project. so we can build our project(Dynamic WEB) without GWT compiling.
But in NetBeans we dont have this approach! If we build web project at first GWT will be compiled. so, How we can change this approach like eclipse ( I want to compile GWT separately in netbeabs)

RGDS

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans, you can use .nbm files first.  And then you have to change  **gwt.properties** file in line:

> gwt.install.dir=C:/gwt-windows-2.4.0

in Windows, and

> gwt.install.dir=/home/wanto/GWT1.7.1/gwt-linux-2.4.0

in Linux.

Before doing that, you must download GWT from Google (about GWT for Windows or GWT for Linux).